# To connect Hadoop (Hive apis) database in Jax - RS rest service - Netbeans

Tags: java, rest, hadoop, hive, jax-rs

After struggling a lot I managed to have a working code for my Rest service using Jersy -Jax-RS.

My project includes simple database operation with hadoop database. And somehow the errors like :

> org/apache/hive/service/rpc/thrift/TCLIService$Iface
>
> re-run maven with the -e switch
>
> class not found org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

The catch is: Hadoop database connectivity needs many other supporting dependencies to be accompanied with hive-jdbc jar.

Please follow the POM.xml file to have all operations enabled to connect to Hadoop database.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.persistentsys.generateresume</groupId>
    <artifactId>GenerateResume</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestTest</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>RestTest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b03</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: some of the dependencies can be ignored like like: POI and MSSQL

Comment: Hive is not a database... Are you really sure you want to do this? For example large datasets, your HTTP requests will almost certainly timeout waiting for a Hive query to finish. Especially since you're not using Hive2.x... If you really want a database on Hadoop, use Hbase

Answer (score 0):

`hive-jdbc` is the only dependency you need to connect to Hive over JDBC, and the jdbc driver class should be found. It's not clear how you're running the code

It includes libthrift itself, and doesn't require Hadoop dependencies, but if you did add those, the version must match. Don't mix Hadoop 1.x and Hadoop 2.x

Also, you must match the actual versions running in your Hadoop / Hive environment. Hadoop 2.5 and Hive 0.13 are several years old